# ERROR in node-telegram-bot-api Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs', 'net', 'tls' in node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, telegram-bot

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-project\node_modules\mime'
     @ ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/lib/telegramWebHook.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-project\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\lib'
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/lib/telegramWebHook.js 11:9-22
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/lib/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/lib/telegram.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-project\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\lib'
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/lib/telegram.js 31:9-22
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-project\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src'
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js 17:11-24
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegramWebHook.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-project\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src'
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegramWebHook.js 5:11-24
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-project\node_modules\request\lib'
     @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
     @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'my-project\node_modules\forever-agent'
     @ ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24
     @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'my-project\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
     @ ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24
     @ ./node_modules/request-promise/lib/rp.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'my-project\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
     @ ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24
     @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'my-project\node_modules\forever-agent'
     @ ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24
     @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js

    ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'my-project\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
     @ ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24
     @ ./node_modules/request/lib/tunnel.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
     @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js
     @ ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/index.js
     @ ./client/index.js
```

```
<pre>
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home.jsx";

const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = "MY_TOKEN";
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

render(Home, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `require` in a browser application (like react). `require` is for node.js apps, only do `import`.

This telegram bot seems to require access to the filesystem (`fs`) and that is not available in the browser anyway, so you won't be able to use it directly in the frontend.

Sorry for the bad news.